# NSNumber, int, UITextField Error

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

Been stuck on this for a couple of weeks now and researched google a lot but cannot seem to find a solution. I am trying to enter a number into a `UITextField` and save it as an int in a database. I have had this working on another project but I get the error message:

> implicit conversion of int to nsnumber is disallowed with arc

Here is the code I am using

```
NSNumber *firstInt = [score1TF.text intValue];
self.person.int1 = firstInt;
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[score1TF.text intValue]` returns an `int`, and you're trying to assign that to an `NSNumber *` variable, which isn't allowed.  Assuming `self.person.int1` is an `int`, you are looking for:

```
self.person.int1 = [score1TF.text intValue];
```

If it's an `NSNumber *`, you want:

```
self.person.int1 = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[score1TF.text intValue]];
```

Comment: Thank you so much, and thanks for the simple but very clear answer